# how to work with two product(app) in a single workspace in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I just want two apps being developed in a single workspace. Both should have different names. how can I do it in **windows phone 8**?

Comment: What do you mean? Example please.

Comment: like if my workspace has two apps(named a and b). If i open the app a i'll display a textbox and an image if it is app b then i will display only the image(same image).

Comment: `workspace` as in the `solution` of Visual Studio? Do you want two apps or just two ways to open an app?

Comment: yes in visual studio. I want to two apps(which differ slighlty in code) and not two ways

Comment: technically speaking generating two xap's from a single solution file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many different windows phone projects as you like to a solution.

Put all shared code in a shared library. Simples!